# The annotation @FOS\RestBundle\\Controller\Annotations\POST in method ProductBundle\Controller\productsApiController::topProducts() does not exist

Tags: symfony

I have a project in symfony 3.3 everything is working fine in my localhost .But when I uploaded on server it gives me following errors.

> [Semantical Error] The annotation
>   \"@FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\POST\" in method
>   ProductBundle\Controller\productsApiController::topProducts() does
>   not exist, or could not be auto-loaded in
>   /home/techn43k/public_html/sym3.3crm/src/ProductBundle/Controller/
>   (which is being imported from
>   \"/home/techn43k/public_html/sym3.3crm/app/config/routing.yml\"). Make
>   sure annotations are enabled.

Please let me know where is issue. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you did?

Comment: How does looks your "uploading" procedure? Maybe you are not installing all vendors, or your config file is different?

Comment: i just uploaded  my localhost folder on the server  and changed the db parameters

Comment: as i said everything is working fine in my local machine . I think all vendors are installed there isn't any issues in local side.

Comment: product:
    resource: "@ProductBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

Comment: Please let me know what is the procedure when we upload  the code on server. plzz

Comment: @shazzAbbasi We use https://deployer.org/ in our company and i use it in my small projects, to deploy code on servers.

Comment: thnks let me chk

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue .**POST to Post**

```
 /**
 * @Rest\POST("/api/employeelogin")
 */
```

To

```
/**
 * @Rest\Post("/api/employeelogin")
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing on Windows and deploying on linux, make sure that you have no typos on camel case capitalization. Windows is case insensitive, so auto loading files works even if you have some case related typos. Linux is case sensitive, so auto loading requires strictly 0 case typos.

Other than that, make sure that you composer update, and clear and warm-up the cache on your production server

Comment: i have cleared the cache and warmp-up the cache but still showing same error